# IE8 display overlap occurs using insertBefore

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm attempting to move div elements from one section to another using node.insertBefore and order the insertion alphabetically. Upon clicking (in this case clicking `A`) to reorder I have a problem with elements overlapping as seen in the image below:

[image: Element overlap problem]

The code I'm using to produce this follows; I'm sorry it's a little long, but if you copy it into an html file in it's entirety you'll easily see my problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var moveUp, moveDown;

      var moveUp = function() {
        var e = window.event.srcElement;
        var firstBlock = document.getElementById('firstBlock');
        var moved = false;
        for (var i=0; i<firstBlock.childNodes.length; i++) {
          if (firstBlock.childNodes[i].innerText > e.innerText) {
            firstBlock.insertBefore(e, firstBlock.childNodes[i]);
            moved = true;
            break;
          }
          if (!moved) firstBlock.appendChild(e);
        }
        e.onclick = moveDown;
      };

      var moveDown = function() {
        var e = window.event.srcElement;
        var secondBlock = document.getElementById('secondBlock');
        var moved = false;
        for (var i=0; i<secondBlock.childNodes.length; i++) {
          if (secondBlock.childNodes[i].innerText > e.innerText) {
            secondBlock.insertBefore(e, secondBlock.childNodes[i]);
            moved = true;
            break;
          }
          if (!moved) secondBlock.appendChild(e);
        }
        e.onclick = moveUp;
      };

    </script>

    <title>Test</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="firstBlock" style="background-color:#dddddd;">
      <div onclick="moveDown()">A</div>
      <div onclick="moveDown()">B</div>
      <div onclick="moveDown()">C</div>
      <div onclick="moveDown()">D</div>
    </div>

    <div id="secondBlock">
      <div onclick="moveUp()">E</div>
      <div onclick="moveUp()">F</div>
      <div onclick="moveUp()">G</div>
      <div onclick="moveUp()">H</div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong/odd? Can this be fixed/worked around? Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:**

- I can't currently test in any other browsers.
- I notice that once one section fills up, the highlighting no longer readjusts itself when items move between sections.

**Edit 2: Result of jsfiddle posted by Jared**
[image: jsfiddle example]

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/DAVQ9/ (From what was posted in the question.) At least with my fiddle version, Firefox doesn't show the overlap, but you should test that fiddle in your IE before we draw too may conclusions.

Comment: At least in IE9's compatibility/browser mode = IE8, I don't see the overlap.

Comment: Note, I wasn't using the [XHTML Transitional Doctype](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/DAVQ9/1/) in my previous example, but it appears to make no difference. Please provide a working demonstration of the problem you're having; otherwise, not sure how to support your problem.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - no issue in Chrome too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and effort so far. The page displays but as soon as I try to click one of the letters I get an error from some of the jsfiddle code (Message: Object expected // Line: 60 // Char: 1 // Code: 0 // URI: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/). Any suggestions?

Comment: @mkingston - I could fill up the boxes and come out of it too, unlike what you mention

Comment: In the fiddle, change the first dropdown under framework to `on wrap (head)` and run. it will work.

Comment: Thanks @bPratik. I get the same problem in the fiddle as I do in the browser itself. I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: If you can't test in any other browser, can you at least test in IE using Chrome Frame? https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry. Silly super constrained environment. I guess I'll just have to work around it somehow if nobody else can reproduce it. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to come back to this question now. In case anyone else is having this problem, I ended up having to replace the `div` list with a table and rearrange table rows. Another option may be to use a list.